# Having trouble with pathing my express-handlebars

Tags: express, express-handlebars

Here is the layout of the relevant folders in my current project:

- package.json
- develop

  - server.js
  - routes

    - htmlRoutes.js
  - controllers

    - userControl.js
  - views

    - home.handlebars
    - profile.handlebars
    - layouts

      - main.handlebars

The URL I'm trying to go to is: '/users/profile/:id'

1. htmlRoutes.js is linked correctly to my server.js
2. My htmlRoutes.js imports a function from userControl.js (in controllers)
3. My userControls.js is where I have my code that's supposed to take the user to their profile.

Relevant lines of code:

- Server.js

```js
app.use('/', require('./routes/htmlRoutes'))
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
    layoutsDir: (path.join(__dirname, '/views/layouts')), 
    defaultLayout:'main'}
))
```

- htmlRoutes.js

```js
const { takeUserToProfile } = require('../controllers/userControl')

// this one actually works
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render(path.join(__dirname, '../views/home'))
})

router.get('/users/profile/:id', takeUserToProfile)
```

- userControl.js

```js
// this one gives me an error
exports.takeUserToProfile = async (req, res) => {
    const data = await User.findById(req.params.id)
    res.render('profile', {
        username: data.username,
        firstName: data.firstName,
        lastName: data.lastName
    })
}
```

I tried many different things and all I get is an error like this:

Error: Failed to lookup view "profile" in views directory "C:\Users\User\Desktop\repoName\views"

Is there any way to tell my file that there's a 'develop' folder between my repoName and views?